# How to show that $ \ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [0,\frac{1}{n}) \neq \emptyset \ $?

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that $ \ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [0,\frac{1}{n}) \neq \emptyset \ $ ?

**Answer:**

From intuition , we see that

$ \ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [0,\frac{1}{n})=\{0 \} \ $

**But I can't prove it mathematically**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ belongs to all of the intervals, so the intersection is non-empty for sure. Now say $x>0$ was in the intersection. By the Archimedean property, we can always find a natural number $n$ such that $1/n<x$, but then $x\notin [0,1/n)$, so $x$ can't be in the intersection either.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full proof that the intersection is non-empty, with all the details one could reasonably ask for:

For any $n$, we have $0\in [0,\frac1n)$. Therefore $0$ is also contained in the intersection of all these intervals.